# Out of gas ethereum transaction. Didn't roll back?

Tags: out-of-gas

I sent ether to an ICO from my poloniex wallet. But it says out of gas error. And the ether I sent didn't come back to my wallet. What should I do?
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/MOd7j.png)

[image]

Comment: You should contact with your exchange support immediately.

Answer (score 2):

If you confirm that the ether is in fact still at the source address, you should contact Poloniex support. They may be able to confirm nothing was sent and credit your account balance that amount.

In the future, you may want to use your own wallet when contributing to ICOs, especially if they plan to send tokens to that address. If Poloniex never supports that token, it will be unreachable for you.

Comment: i am checking my poloniex wallet, it says transaction completed and there is no ethereum in my wallet.

Answer (score 1):

Exchanges, typically, NEVER support ICOs. Always go into an ICO with that mindset.

You should always send in ETH through your own personal wallet. MEW, Ledger Nano S, Digital Bitbox, etc...

Contact Polonix's support team. I'm sure they can verify they still have your ether and credit it back to your account.